# java arrays error: /tmp/java_959p0x/TestPrimeDividers.java:30: error: cannot find symbol return arr;

Tags: java, arrays, symbols

Can you please help me figure out why I am getting an error in this Java program?

```
public class TestPrimeDividers {
    public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int i = 2; i < n && flag ; i++) {
            if ((n % i) == 0)
                flag = false;
        }
        return flag;
    }
    public static long [] primeDividers(long n) {
        if (isPrime(n)) {
            long arr[] = new long [0];
            return arr;
        } else {
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 2 ; i < n; i++)
                if (isPrime(i))
                    j++;
            long arr[] = new long [j];
            j = 0;
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
                if (isPrime(i)) {
                    arr[j] = i;
                    j++;
                }

        }
        return arr;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long arr [] = primeDividers(6);
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
/tmp/java_959p0x/TestPrimeDividers.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
return arr;
       ^
  symbol:   variable arr
  location: class TestPrimeDividers
1 error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 2):

In Java, variables are scoped to the blocks in which they are declared.  Your method `primeDividers` declares two different variables named `arr`, both within different nested blocks; neither is accessible at the top level.  Therefore, when you try to return `arr` from the top level of the method, you get an error.

Try declaring your variable at the top of your function, before you enter any nested blocks.